# Could not restart app server(s) for '': Environment named "" is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there any way of getting elastic beanstalk out of this state:

> Could not restart app server(s) for '': Environment named is in an
>   invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.

I do not want to rebuild it, nor can i restart, redeploy or clone.